# Multiple criteria unique values, and list

Tags: microsoft-excel, array, deduplication, list

I have two issues that I am looking for help with.

The first is to create a dynamic list of unique ID numbers for items matching "Horse" in column `J` on `Sheet 2!`, "Ball" in column `I` on `Sheet 2!`, and that do not contain the word dog in column `A` on `Sheet 2!` In the example below, this would return the ID numbers 48 and 56

The second, is that while I have calculated the number of assets meeting this criteria (3) , using

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet2!$A:$A, "<>*Dog*", Sheet2!$J:$J, "Horse", Sheet2!$I:$I, "Ball")
```

I would like to calculate the number of unique entries as well, which would be 2 in the example provided,

[image: Graph Example]

Comment: Better share some sample data and expected result with us will help us to fix the issue in better way!!

Comment: @RajeshS good suggestion! updated with an example

Comment: ,, check my post I've solved the issue ☺

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**How the formula works:**

1. In `Sheet 1` write criteria **Dog, Ball & Horse**, in Cell `F2, G2 & H2`.
2. Cell Range `C3:C10` of `Sheet 1` has **IDs**.
3. Write this Array Formula in cell `A13` of `Sheet 1`, finish with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter` & fill it down.

   ```
   {=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$10, MATCH(1, (COUNTIF($A$12:A12,$C$3:$C$10)=0)*(Sheet2!$A$3:$A$10<>$F$2)*(Sheet2!$I$3:$I$10=$G$2)*(Sheet2!$J$3:$J$11=$H$2), 0)),"")}
   ```

*Adjust cell references in the Formula as needed.*

Comment: Thank you! I'm trying to get this formula to work for me but am still getting errors. In my workbook all of the data in A-D is in Sheet 2 and the formula is in Sheet 1. I can put F-G look up terms in Sheet 1, but can't move the data to Sheet 1.

Comment: @VictoriaG,, **I've created solution on the basis of information you have provided**,, now what you have to do is, adjust Formula with Range,,, better first try Formula in Sheet2 then use in Sheet1.

Comment: @VictoriaG, suppose you have ID also in Sheet2 along with other Pet, Toy & Animal then try the Formula without Sheet Name as prefix,,, create criteria also in Sheet 2!!

Comment: I appreciate the help, unfortunately I still can't get it to work. I am getting circular reference errors or a 0 each time I try to use the code on either sheet.

Comment: @VictoriaG,, better you put all data in ONE Sheet,,`A2:D9` put Criteria also there and use the Command, then try in Two different Sheets. The suggested formula is 100% working and the Screen Shot is part of the  active Sheet!